# using Raphael's-library for drawing left aligned text

Tags: javascript, alignment, raphael

I am using Raphael's JavaScript library (http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw some graphics into my web-application. I tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael/raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <script>
        var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 600, 200);            
        paper.text(300, 50, "first very very long line\nshort line").attr(
            {"font-family":"arial", 
            "font-size":"30",
            "text-align":"left"}
            );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is a graphic with two lines of text that are centered. The css font-family and font-size are displayed correct. But the css text-align is ignored. Why?

(tested with Firefox 8.0 and Chrome 15)

Comment: ok I just found the answer:

use "text-anchor":"start" instead of "text-align":"left".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that [Raphael doesn't use `text-align` property](https://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/4a05846e8e4262c2?pli=1). Instead use the [`text-anchor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#AlignmentProperties) property, its possible values are `start`, `middle`, `end` or `inherit`.

In your example use it like this:

```
paper.text(300, 50, "first very very long line\nshort line").attr({
    "font-family":"arial", 
    "font-size":"30",
    "text-anchor":"start"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
paper.text(300, 50, "first very very long line\nshort line").attr(
            {"font-family":"arial", 
            "font-size":"30",
            "text-anchor":"start"}
            );
```